# unable to set updated partial view data to div. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am showing a list (partial view) on my view and the view has a "Add" button. Clicking on "Add" I go to different view and the action there redirect me back to the list view ..

```
return RedirectToAction("List", "Home");
```

The issue is as following : --

- Suppose I have 4 items to the list .. Item1, Item2, Item3 and Item4
- When I go to the list page from menu .. all 4 items are there.
- Then I click to add and add the Item5 there This actiob redirect me
  back to list page ... but I can see only 4 items here ..
- then I manually reload the page by pressing enter on browser's
  address bar ..
- Now I can see 5 items ..  .. again .. Add .. no new item displaying
  in the list. .. :(

To show the list I am using partial view ..

**Tried following: both are giving same result :(**

Method 1.

```
<div id="showListHere">
  @{ Html.RenderAction("ShowList", "Home"); }
</div>
```

Method 2.

```
  $(function(){

        // Load list
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){               
                $.ajax({
                    url :'@Url.Action("ShowList", "Home")',                 
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#showListHere').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

Controller code :

```
[HttpGet]       
public ActionResult ShowList()
{
    var result = MyFunctions.GetListResult();
    return PartialView("_ListPartialView", result);
}
```

Please share suggestions ..

Comment: Your first 2 snippets are calling `ShowList()` but the method you have shown is `GetList()`

Comment: I assume it is being cached. Try adding `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` to the `ShowList()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue once .. the reason was that my add process was taking time .. before completing the add process I was showing data to my view. My action was aync Task. ..

**Solution : --** 
Show progress bar until the action is completely done and then show the result.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: thanks .. the issue was almost same .. marking as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want for your added item to show you will need to refresh the page after adding the item OR use AJAX and update the list after adding the item.

Comment: OP is redirecting after adding the item!

Comment: @PinHead877 functioning to add the item is at different view .. and I am using "return RedirectToAction(....)" to come back to the list

Comment: can you post the method you useing to GET the result from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Both Method 1 And Method 2 Would work provided, Your Function
`GetListResult()` is getting all the 5 items from the Database.